# Where can I find some CMS usage statistics?

Tags: cms, usage-data

Does anyone know a place where I can find some usage statistics on different CMSs? Also, do folks actually believe the massive massive Drupal share [given here](http://trends.builtwith.com/cms)? ([Netcraft claimed](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2009/10/27/white_house_goes_open_source.html) that Drupal was the sixth largest PHP-based CMS about a year ago; wish I could find the top five.)

Comment: I think you found them there already: http://trends.builtwith.com/cms

Comment: You know I find it so difficult to believe that Drupal is that popular! Google Trends shows many many more searches for Joomla than Drupal (which is of course just a measure of searches), and as I mentioned, Netcraft placed it sixth a year ago (and I trust Netcraft). I'd love to see some other sources... (btw I'm a die-hard Drupal developer, so it's not that I don't like it;)

Comment: That is a weird site. For one they count forum software as "Content Management" but then neglect Wordpress?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: It's a wierd taxonomy, but they seem to keep track of blogging platforms in a separate section: http://trends.builtwith.com/blog

Comment: That builtwith.com site is really funny. Not only are the data a mix and match all over the place, but they also provide this gem: "Citrix® NetScaler® is a Web application delivery appliance that makes applications run five times better."  Better than what?

Comment: Wooo, those data seems like inaccurate to me... Seriously vBulletin in 2nd place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I've found these stats to be the best:**

- http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/content_management/all

If you click any of the CMS systems listed, it'll tell you the the 10 most popular sites using that CMS. The page also breaks down what % of each version is being used.

**Here's an overview of how they did the research, which to me makes sense:**

- http://w3techs.com/technologies

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted appears to be fairly inaccurate as pointed out [here](http://www.alltogetherasawhole.org/profiles/blogs/cms-usage-statistics-drupal) among other places (Drupal is over-counted). Plus it ignores Wordpress which is perfectly usable as a CMS.

Although unscientific, I think the best place is Google Trends since it clearly shows which CMS have the most buzz around them. [Trends for Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal and Expression Engine](http://www.google.com/trends?q=wordpress,+joomla,+drupal,+expression+engine&ctab=0&geo=us&geor=all&date=all&sort=0) shows roughly this:

- Worldwide: 50% Wordpress, 36% Joomla, 12% Drupal, 2% EE.
- United States: 61% Wordpress, 21% Joomla, 15% Drupal, 3% EE.

However all four of those systems are well-supported so I wouldn't use any figures like these to decide on a CMS - choose whichever one best meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks, yeah was wondering if anything better than trends was around. I don't want the stats to choose, I'm just interested in following the trends.